# Help needed with LINQ to SQL Syntax

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Hi there i'm getting mixed up trying to build a group by result set in LINQ

The following TSQL gets what i want in LINQ, the expression is:

```
select s.SiteDescription,count(*) as TotalIncidents
from Site as s,Incident as i
where s.SiteId = i.SiteId
group by s.SiteDescription
```

But I want to create the same thing in LINQ in my Controller code, here is what i have but its no good and i'm all over the place today :

```
var qry = from s in _db.Sites
            join i in _db.Incidents on s.SiteId equals i.SiteId
            group s.SiteDescription
                into grp
                select new
                {
                    Site = grp.Key,
                    Count = grp.Select(x => x.Incidents).Distinct().Count()
                };
```

My errors are :

> Error 27
>   Cannot convert lambda  expression to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer'
>   because it is not a delegate
>   type  C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\IRenewables_EMAS\IRenewables_EMAS\Controllers\IncidentController.cs    40  23  Emas.Web
>   Error 28
>   The type arguments for method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try
>   specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\IRenewables_EMAS\IRenewables_EMAS\Controllers\IncidentController.cs    51  33  Emas.Web
>   Error 29
>   Expected contextual keyword 'by'  C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\IRenewables_EMAS\IRenewables_EMAS\Controllers\IncidentController.cs    41  27  Emas.Web

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: *it's no good* - no good how?? No results? Wrong results?

Comment: thanks marc i've pasted in build errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var qry =   from s in _db.Sites
            join i in _db.Incidents on s.SiteId equals i.SiteId
            group s by s.SiteDescription into grp
            select new
            {
                Site = grp.Key,
                Count =  grp.Count()
            };
```